# Как поверх блока добавить заливку цветом?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пжл, как можно поверх блока сделать заливку полупрозрачным цветом и поместить поверх заливки надпись (что форма временно не работает)? Пробывал даже через z-index, и др функции наложения. Прикрепил код и фото

Заранее спасибо)

[image: Что должно получиться]

```css
.question-mail-form {
    background: white;
padding: 120px 39px 0px;
padding-top: 0;
border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
height: 597px !important;
}

hr {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

hr {
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 52px;
    width: 167px;
    margin-top: 71px;
    border-color: #eaeaea;
}

.form-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

form {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0em;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 418px;
    height: 45px;
}

.placeholder {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    padding: 0 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(80, 145, 250, 0.7);
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.message {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 418px;
    min-height: 149px;
    resize: none;
    padding-top: 17px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.btn-form {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 0;
    background: #5091FA;
    padding: 15px 39px;
    width: 170px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.p-checkbox {
    max-width: 372px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: rgba(26, 43, 72, 0.6);
}

.checkbox {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-mail-form">
            <hr>
            <form name="form" action="" method="post" id="form_message" class="form-main">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше Имя" class="placeholder" name="name" required="">

            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="placeholder" name="email" required="">

            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Сообщение" class="placeholder message" required=""></textarea>

<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked=""> <p class="p-checkbox">Я выражаю свое согласие на обработку моих персональных данных в соответствие с  <a class="a-checkbox" href="#">Политикой обработки и защиты персональных данных</a></p>
</div>

 <div id="form_result"></div>

            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-form">Отправить</button>
                    </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: хосподи... да это просто ещё один блок со сто процентной шириной и высотой и с background rgba + в нём текст отцентрированный

Comment: @MaximLensky или псевдоэлемент

Comment: Еще один div создать в divе с формой?

Comment: @Deonis да возможно

Comment: да ниже вашей формы - и расположить абсолютно

Comment: в моем случает абсолютное разлазиется на весь экран и при падингах остаются белые полосы (не весь покрывает)

Comment: Для элемента `.question-mail-form` добавьте свойства: `position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;` (https://jsfiddle.net/jxhm5w69/)

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZEerddZ - вот так примерно .. ноя не следовал вашей разметке

Comment: @Deonis можно ли как-то добавить отступы для текста по лево и право?  Пришлось добавить текст а он упирается прям в края

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKWQOZj - это ваша форма

Comment: Огромное спасибо ребят!!! Пол года верстаю и обучаюсь параллельно и уже просто так выдохся, что даже забыл про свойство overflow ох

Comment: owerflow там и не нужно так как абсолютный блок должен подстроиться под родительский

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так

```css
.question-mail-form {
  background: white;
  padding: 120px 39px 0px;
  padding-top: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  height: 597px !important;
  width: 312px;
  position: relative;
  /* чтобы ограничить absolute ребенка*/
}

.form-overlap {
  position: absolute;
  /* чтобы перекрывать соседние элементы */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0095ff7d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.form-overlap__text {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

hr {
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 52px;
  width: 167px;
  margin-top: 71px;
  border-color: #eaeaea;
}

.form-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0em;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 418px;
  height: 45px;
}

.placeholder {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(80, 145, 250, 0.7);
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.message {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 418px;
  min-height: 149px;
  resize: none;
  padding-top: 17px;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.btn-form {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  background: #5091FA;
  padding: 15px 39px;
  width: 170px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.p-checkbox {
  max-width: 372px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: rgba(26, 43, 72, 0.6);
}

.checkbox {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-mail-form">
  <div class="form-overlap">
    <div class="form-overlap__text">Форма временно не работает</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <form name="form" action="" method="post" id="form_message" class="form-main">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше Имя" class="placeholder" name="name" required="">

    <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="placeholder" name="email" required="">

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Сообщение" class="placeholder message" required=""></textarea>

    <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="">
      <p class="p-checkbox">Я выражаю свое согласие на обработку моих персональных данных в соответствие с <a class="a-checkbox" href="#">Политикой обработки и защиты персональных данных</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="form_result"></div>

    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-form">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```